# how to fetch state parameter from google app

Tags: php, state, google-oauth

[google login](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/sbs/googlelogin/index.php&client_id=%2a%2a43760%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a-cp7keq4lsesqf36a0kel9f5761l5i0pc.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&state=reg)

I am working on php . I have made app on Google . If u can see my link , I am using state parameter , in which **state=reg** . In my callback page , I am trying to get this value ie $_get['state'] but its not showing me anything . Am i doing the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen a Client ID that begins "**", but in your link I see client_id=%2a%2a43760%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a-cp7 which really looks wonky.  Are you sure that’s right?

Comment: I'm guessing he's obfuscated his client id for the purposes of this post